# Object is undefined outside a return statement, but is accessible in a component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I'm curious as to why useState is giving me undefined for something that can be used inside JSX:

The following is outside the return statement:

```
useEffect(() => dispatch(fetchMessages()), [dispatch]);

const isLoading = useLoadingState(ApiAction.fetchMessages);
const { messages } = useSelector<MessagesState>((state) => state.messages);
const [filteredMessages, setFilteredMessages] = useState<AdminMessages[]>();
useEffect(() => setFilteredMessages(messages), [messages]);
```

And while messages is an array of objects, filteredMessages is undefined

However, filteredMessages can be rendered inside the return statement in an ant-design components as follows:

```
return (
  <Table
    rowClassName="Table__row"
    dataSource={filteredMessages}
    rowKey="id"
    pagination={false}
  >
  // etc.
```

Why is `filteredMessages` undefined outside the `return` statement, but is then accessible inside when fed into the component?

Comment: It's not clear what the actual issue is. `filteredMessages` will be undefined until set by the `useEffect`, and setting state is async. Just a guess, but you're attempting to access it somewhere before the state update has completed.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you create `filteredMessages` state and update it using `useEffect`. State updates are not visible immediately - instead they will trigger new re-render and then with the next component call the updated state will be passed.

So in your case I recommend handling undefined case and defaulting to `messages`:

```
return (
  <Table
    rowClassName="Table__row"
    dataSource={filteredMessages || messages}
    rowKey="id"
    pagination={false}
  >
  // etc.
```

You can also set initial state by passing `messages` to `useState` function. By default initial state is undefined.

Comment: Passing in messages helped
const [filteredMessages, setFilteredMessages] = useState<AdminMessages[]>(messages);

However, when I console.log, messages.length is 0 until the third render. Is this typical React behavior? Is there a way to wait until the state has been updated before re-rendering?

Comment: The more side effect you use, the more component will be called. But don't worry- react automatically optimise actual renders. In your case you can set default state by passing it to useState (`useState<AdminMessages[]>(messages)`). However your state still can be undefined (cause you call fetchMessages at first), so in the first render messages either undefined or empty list.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) is the "initial state" value. You didn't pass in an initial value, so the initial value is `undefined`:

```
const [filteredMessages, setFilteredMessages] = useState<AdminMessages[]>();
```

> During the initial render, the returned state (state) is the same as the value passed as the first argument (initialState).

However, later on you call `setFilteredMessages()` which then sets the state:

```
useEffect(() => setFilteredMessages(messages), [messages]);
```